# React three Fiber Cube doesn't show up

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to render a rotating cube on my DOM, but for some reason, the following code does not show anything.

I don't get any errors either.

```
function Cube(){
  const meshRef = useRef<Mesh>(null); 

   useFrame((state, delta) => (meshRef.current.rotation.x += delta))


  return(
    <mesh ref={meshRef}>
     <boxGeometry/>
      <meshStandardMaterial/>
    </mesh>
  )
}

function App() {


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Canvas>
        <Cube />
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: can you post your code on Code sandbox and share a link

Comment: I posted it on a Sandbox and got an error I wasn't getting on vscode -> error:" Function components cannot have string refs. We recommend using useRef() instead." The error has to do with the <Mesh> in useRef, I removed it and it worked. But I don't know why the tutorial I was watching used the <Mesh> this way, it's an up to date tutorial too.

Comment: can you send the link without the <Mesh>

Comment: Here: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-sky-2w0496?file=/src/App.js

Comment: change ur file to .tsx it should fix it for <Mesh>

Comment: I posted it as an answer if you want to accept it as a fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change ur file to .tsx it should fix it for